# How to get attributes of an Object in Java?

Tags: java

I have a function that returns an `Object`

The `toString()` method shows that my object has two `BigDecimal` attributes. But I don't know how to get them in the code ?

[image]

My function uses hibernate to get results from a query is :

```
public Object executeQuery(final String sql) {
    final Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    return query.list().get(0);
}
```

Thank you.

-- Additional infos:

```
obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); // empty array []
obj.getClass().getName();           // [Ljava.lang.Object;
final BigDecimal b = (BigDecimal) obj[0]; //Compilation error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object
```

Comment: If you know the object type,typecast it to that type.

Comment: @Renjith I don't know the type. In my screenshot there's no particular type.

Comment: Dont you have mapping class for the table which you are querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your comments, your Object is and Object array.

So you should first cast the result to an Object array:

```
Object[] obj = (Object[]) query.list().get(0);
```

Then, you should be able to access the first BigDecimal like that:

```
BigDecimal b = (BigDecimal) obj[0];
```

Probably, you want to add some exception handling.

Comment: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object`

Comment: I haven't casted the object though.. let me check

Answer (score 4):

`obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` can help you. Generally learn reflection API. If you object bean you can also use Jackarta BeanUtils.

Comment: In that case the class doesn't have any fields. You might need to get the super class's fields (and it's super class as well)

Comment: what super class above the class Object ?

Comment: Generally that is true, but for the current situation it was visible from the screenshot that he has an array (I was blind, as well). So, now it is inappropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

You have a resultset with 2 columns.

```
Object[] result= query.list().get(0);
BigDecimal number1 = (BigDecimal) result[0];
BigDecimal number2 = (BigDecimal) result[1];
```

Comment: my object is of type `Object`

Comment: The runtime type is not `Object`. Try `obj.getClass().getName()` - it will give you the actual runtime type of your object.

Comment: `obj.getClass().getName()` returns `[Ljava.lang.Object;`.

Comment: As far as I can see, you made a JPA query for a certain object. You should cast the result to that object.

Comment: @MajidLAISSI `[L` in the `[Ljava.lang.Object` shows that it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Get first what class name of that object by

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass());
```

Since you are running a sql query, result might be an `Entity` or `Object[]`.

when you came to know retrieved object from query is an `Object[]` you can iterate like

```
if( obj instanceof Object[] ) {
       Object[] objA = (Object[])obj;
       for(Object atomicObj : objA ) {
         System.out.println(atomicObj);
       }
}
```

It works for all elements which presents in object array. This time you may get BigDecimal, next query might return a `String` and `BigDecimal`.

Comment: see edit and my other comments : `obj.getClass().getName();` --> `[Ljava.lang.Object;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not an Object, it is an Array of Objects.

```
BigDecimal firstColumn = (BigDecimal) ((Object[])query.list().get(0))[0];
BigDecimal secondColumn = (BigDecimal) ((Object[])query.list().get(0))[1];
```

That's all.